# Make custom hook be dependent on React Query hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I have a problem with using my custom hook after using a useQuery hook.

Catalogue.jsx

```
import { Box, Spinner } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import ProductPage from "../../components/Products/ProductPage";
import useBeers from "../../hooks/useBeers";
import useProductData from "../../hooks/useProductData";

const Catalogue = () => {
  const { data: products, isLoading } = useBeers();

  const productData = useProductData(products);

  if (isLoading) return <Spinner />;

  return (
    <Box>
      <ProductPage productData={productData} />
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Catalogue;
```

So, i want my useProductData execute only if have already got products from useBeers.
useBeers.js

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";

const useBeers = () =>
  useQuery({
    queryKey: ["beer"],
    queryFn: () =>
      axios.get("localhost:3001/api/beers").then((response) => response.data),
  });

export default useBeers;
```

useProductData.js

```
import { useState } from "react";

function useProductData(products) {
  const brands = products.map(({ id, brand }) => ({
    id,
    brand,
  }));
  const prices = products.map((item) => item.price);
  const min = Math.min(...prices);
  const max = Math.max(...prices);

  const title = "Crowlers"; // TODO

  const uniqueBrands = brands.filter(
    (item, index, self) =>
      index === self.findIndex((t) => t.brand === item.brand)
  );

  const [filteredValues, setFilteredValues] = useState([min, max]);
  const [checkedBrands, setCheckedBrands] = useState({});

  const brandFilterData = { uniqueBrands, checkedBrands, setCheckedBrands };
  const priceFilterData = { min, max, filteredValues, setFilteredValues };

  const isVoucher = products.every((product) =>
    product.name.includes("Voucher")
  );

  return {
    filteredValues,
    checkedBrands,
    products,
    title,
    brandFilterData,
    priceFilterData,
    isVoucher,
  };
}

export default useProductData;
```

I tried changing the order of lines to execute useProductData only if !isLoading like this but it didn`t work as i expected, i had an error:
React Hook "useProductData" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?

```
const { data: products, isLoading } = useBeers();

  if (isLoading) return <Spinner />;

  const productData = useProductData(products);
```

Comment: You can't do it that way. Simplest fix would be to add a layer in the component hierarchy and conditionally render a component that takes the data from useBeers as props and calls the useProductData hook. But you may want to re-think how you're doing this...

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
const getStuffFromProducts = (products) => {
  const brands = products.map(({ id, brand }) => ({
    id,
    brand,
  }));
  const prices = products.map((item) => item.price);
  const min = Math.min(...prices);
  const max = Math.max(...prices);

  const title = "Crowlers"; // TODO

  const uniqueBrands = brands.filter(
    (item, index, self) =>
      index === self.findIndex((t) => t.brand === item.brand)
  );

  return {min, max, uniqueBrands};
}
function useProductData(products) {
  const {min, max, uniqueBrands} = getStuffFromProducts(products)

  const [filteredValues, setFilteredValues] = useState([min, max]);
  const [checkedBrands, setCheckedBrands] = useState({});

  const brandFilterData = { uniqueBrands, checkedBrands, setCheckedBrands };
  const priceFilterData = { min, max, filteredValues, setFilteredValues };

  const isVoucher = products.every((product) =>
    product.name.includes("Voucher")
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const {min, max} = getStuffFromProducts(products);
    setFilteredValues([min, max])

  }, [products])

  return {
    filteredValues,
    checkedBrands,
    products,
    title,
    brandFilterData,
    priceFilterData,
    isVoucher,
  };
}
```

with a bit of a cleanup ofc, but that's the gist of it

Answer (score 0):

So, i resolved this issue by passing products to the ProductPage component, not ProductData and getting ProductData inside ProductPage component like this

Catalogue.jsx

```
import { Box, Spinner } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import ProductPage from "../../components/Products/ProductPage";
import useBeers from "../../hooks/useBeers";

const Catalogue = () => {
  const { data: products, isLoading } = useBeers();

  if (isLoading) return <Spinner />;

  return <Box>{products && <ProductPage products={products} />}</Box>;
};

export default Catalogue;
```

ProductPage.jsx

```
const ProductPage = ({ products }) => {
  // Get a pathname to create a redirect component
  const pathname = useLocation().pathname.substring(1);

  const productData = useProductData(products);

  return (
    <>
      <SubscriptionPoster />
      <ProductPageBody pathname={pathname} productData={productData} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -2):

To resolve this issue, ensure that your hooks are called unconditionally, meaning they're called in the same order and at the top level of your functional component.
Try  like this :

```
import { Box, Spinner } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import ProductPage from "../../components/Products/ProductPage";
import useBeers from "../../hooks/useBeers";
import useProductData from "../../hooks/useProductData";

const Catalogue = () => {
  const { data: products, isLoading } = useBeers();

  if (isLoading) return <Spinner />;

  // Move useProductData inside the component body
  const productData = useProductData(products);

  return (
    <Box>
      {products && <ProductPage productData={productData} />}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Catalogue;
```

Comment: This will give the error "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render." as the count of hooks is different between renders.

Comment: for me, it gives the same error:
React Hook "useProductData" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render.

Comment: You can't do early returns before hook calls either. Did you get this from ChatGPT?

Comment: Please annotate this line like this: const { data: products = [], isLoading } = useBeers(); Because before the first render, products are not ready, and attempting to execute a map on something that might not be iterable (as products might be undefined) can cause an error. To prevent this error, adding a default array, as I mentioned before, can ensure that the error doesn't occur due to data being undefined.